Fail to import images from csv file
I use CS-Cart marketplace software to import products to the store using vendor's csv files. For some reason images from this vendor fail to be downloaded with error --Error It is not allowed to upload files with .ashx extension here.--
Here is an image link
https://www.electrolux.ro/remote.jpg.ashx?urlb64=aHR0cHM6Ly9zZXJ2aWNlcy5lbGVjdHJvbHV4LW1lZGlhbGlicmFyeS5jb20vMTE4ZWQ0YzBlZTY1NDZmNGE3Njg0YzdmZWY4Yzk4NWFOclptWWtNODYxZDFmL3ZpZXcvV1NfUE4vUFNFRURSMTkwUEUwMDAwOC5wbmc&hmac=gh4omIw1ca8


If I upload the images via cs-cart product admin area it works fine, it also works on browser,  only the script is failing to download the images. How to alter the script to download this kind of image file links ?
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

If I try with command like using wget I get -Redirecting output to ‘wget-log'

@KenLee did you managed to download the file to your server using curl or get ?

"the script is failing to download the images" - what exactly does that mean?

@NicoHaase I'm using CS-Cart marketplace software to import products to the store using vendor's csv files. For some reason images from this vendor fail to be downloaded.

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, and share the code involved
